# How does browserify work with angular based app?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, browserify

I was mess around this for a couple of days. I was trying to get browserfiy to work well with angular based app. I have tried following options but still cannot decide on a better way to do it, it will be appreciated if anyone can give any suggestion on this.

- Option 1

Bundle all angular related libs, like angular, angular-animate, angular-ui-router, etc into `vendor.js` by using `bundle.require`

Bundle all app reated source files into `app.js` by using `bundle.external`

That works fine in dev environment, all modules in vendor.js could be required from app.js

But it crashed in prod environment. The minified angular files are not all CMD. Although I can `browserify-shim` angular.min.js and `bundle.require` angular-ui-router.min.js, it's kind of cubersome to do this file by file.

- Option 2

Leave all angular libs into `<script>` and only output bundle for app files. That means in app.js, I have to refer to angular as a global var which is not good.

So what's the best practise to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Even if you do `require()` angularjs, it still exposes the `angular` namespace in the context of its environment (`Window` object for browsers). What I usually do is simply put all angularjs modules dependencies (e.g. `ui.router`, `ngResource` and etc) below the bundled(browserified) javascript where your angularjs application resides. In my case, I use `gulp-useref` to concatenate all the script provided by the `gulp-inject` tags(this includes scripts bundled by browserify).

As you may have noticed below, the bower components(`bower:js` tag) are added below the bundle(`inject:js` tag). Since requiring the `angular` module will attach the `angular` object in the `window` object, then any components external to browserify can access `window.angular`.

The answer I provided is somehow similar to option 2 but without the disadvantage of referring `angular` as a global variable within your browserified code.

e.g.

```
<!-- build:js({./.tmp,./}) js/index.js -->
<!-- inject:js -->
<!-- endinject -->
<!-- bower:js -->
<!-- endinject -->
<!-- endbuild -->
```

UPDATE:

I've create a [github repo](https://github.com/ryeballar/angular-browserify) that resembles the answer provided above. Try to clone it, and see what you can do with it.

Comment: So it looks like you `gulp-useref` everyting into one index.js including your app bundle and all angular dependencies from bower. Question is how can you do `require('angular')` by doing the way you show above?

Comment: And how about production environment? Basically you need all minified files, so I think dev and prod should be separated gulp work flow right?

Comment: well you install angular as an npm dependency instead of a bower bower one?

Comment: The production code should be separated after the build.

Comment: Yes, I npm install angular as my first intention is to browserify them into a vendor bundle. From your code, finally there is only index.js?

Comment: hmm yes once everything is built (for production).

Comment: what a huge file, i will still prefer to put angulars in cdn maybe

Comment: Well that depends on your strategy, you can separate minified versions of the bower components and the bundled versions or you can buid and concatenate everything.

Comment: If you keep angularjs in a CDN, then I guess you would be accessing angular using the window object instead of using `require()`, which kind of defeats the whole purpose of containing your application.

Comment: In your suggested way, can you use `require('angular')` ? or `require('angular-ui-router')`?

Comment: The suggestion suggests that you only need to use `require()` when you need to use a module. Since you need angular to create a module then you have use `require()` on it. `The angular-ui-router` does not represent an object, so you don't need to use `require()` on it, simply include it as a script below your bundles.

Comment: Alright, that's my confusion. I think NPM version `angular-ui-router` should do `module.exports` in angular-ui-router.js, not only handle CMD in index.js. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Ok, so angular.js is in the bundle as well. Anyway I like the way you sort gulp out! Especially for a complicated build workflow.